# unique constrain fails with foreignKey field

Tags: django, django-models

I want to make a position model with a foreign key to a category model, but i get a unique constrain error when adding 2 position to one category although the category field is foreignkey model not one-to-one field

i tried many things but it didn't work

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    _type = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)

class Position(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    category = models.IntegerField(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please take a look at your `Position` model. The category field should be defined as either

```
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

or

```
category = models.OneToOneField(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

also, it is generally not accepted that you define a field starting with `_` in django.